# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when adding params to express route

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

I'm getting this error everytime I add a params to my route. It messes with the html file I serve and return a not found html file instead of the js file I have in the html file I served
so like this work

```
app.get('/polls',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/poll.html")
})
```

but this doesn't

```
app.get('/polls/:id',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/poll.html")
})
```

the error is in client-side. There absolutely nothing else except the fact that it call error on line 1 the js file inside poll.html but show line 1 of poll.html in console. here the github directory to it: https://github.com/tienanh2007/Voting-App

Comment: your first piece of code is invalid, because it should be `'/polls'`, not `'/polls`, else you're passing a **string** to app.get, which shouldn't be so happy about that. (also, it should not even compile as far as I know)

Comment: oh right just a typo in this post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

just put `publicPath: '/',` on your output in webpack.config.js file